# How to check a time-range in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
time             
2018-06-25 20:42:00
2016-06-26 23:51:00
2017-05-34 12:29:00
2016-03-11 10:14:00
```

Now I created a column like this
`df['isEIDRange'] = 0`

Let's say, EID festivate is on 15 June 2018.

So I want to fill `1` value in `isEIDRange` column. If the date is between 10 June 2018 to 20 June 2018 (5 days before and 5 days after EID)

How can I do it?

Something like?

`df.loc[ (df.time > 15 June - 5 days) & (df.time < 15 June + 5 days), 'isEIDRange' ] = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loc` or `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['isEIDRange'] = np.where((df['time'] > '2018-06-10') & (df['time'] < '2018-06-20'),1,df['isEIDRange']
```

This means that when the column `time` is between 2018-06-10 and 2018-06-20, the column `isEIDRange` will be equal to 1, otherwise it will retain it's original value (0).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) function for test values with cast mask to integers:

```
df['isEIDRange'] = df['time'].between('2018-06-10', '2018-06-20').astype(int)
```

If want dynamic solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": pd.date_range("2018-06-08", "2018-06-22")})
#print (df)

date = '15 June 2018'
d = pd.to_datetime(date)
diff = pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')

df['isEIDRange1'] = df['time'].between(d - diff, d + diff).astype(int)
df['isEIDRange2'] = df['time'].between(d - diff, d + diff, inclusive=False).astype(int)
print (df)
         time  isEIDRange1  isEIDRange2
0  2018-06-08            0            0
1  2018-06-09            0            0
2  2018-06-10            1            0
3  2018-06-11            1            1
4  2018-06-12            1            1
5  2018-06-13            1            1
6  2018-06-14            1            1
7  2018-06-15            1            1
8  2018-06-16            1            1
9  2018-06-17            1            1
10 2018-06-18            1            1
11 2018-06-19            1            1
12 2018-06-20            1            0
13 2018-06-21            0            0
14 2018-06-22            0            0
```

Or set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['isEIDRange'] = np.where(df['time'].between(d - diff, d + diff), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Nice, I harcoded the difference, I'll my answer as yours more flexible :)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Another off topic question: Jezrael, is there anything like cumlast() in pandas? Just like cumsum()?

Comment: @johndoe - no, only [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html)
[`Series.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html)
[`Series.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html)
[`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas date_range for this:

```
eid = pd.date_range("15/10/2019", "20/10/2019")
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": pd.date_range("13/10/2019", "20/10/2019")})

df["eid"] = 0
df.loc[df["dates"].isin(eid), "eid"] = 1
```

and output:

```
    dates      eid
0   2019-10-13  0
1   2019-10-14  0
2   2019-10-15  1
3   2019-10-16  1
4   2019-10-17  1
5   2019-10-18  1
6   2019-10-19  1
7   2019-10-20  1
```